# paper-button doesn't work, where is the mistake?

Tags: html, polymer

I am learning polymer. Want to link paper-button, but doesn't work. where is the mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Polymer</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

</head>
<body>
    <paper-button>flat button</paper-button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What's it doing or not doing? Have you looked at your Javascript console whether all the imports are loading?

Comment: i didn't check in Javascript console, how to do that?

Comment: Figure out where your browser's developer tools are, you'll be amazed at what's there and how easy they'll make your life.

Comment: i know it, but i don't know how to check that my links are loading or not. can you explain?

Comment: Have a look at the network tab and/or resource tab, see if those files are being found and loaded. Look at the Javascript console whether there are any errors.

Comment: there is no errors at the nerwork and resource tabs, but console has error: Imported resource from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: So, how are you opening this file exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is working with a proper bower configuration. Here is the single module I installed, I guess this is your problem:

```
bower install Polymer/paper-elements
```

This is documented in the guide [*Using elements*](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/usingelements.html) of the *Polymer* project.

Comment: i've done that, I suppose links are not loading, how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8bb54bfr/). it is working. 
I make it using following way. I think your imported links are not loading.

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js?20150316"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">


<body>
     <paper-button>flat button</paper-button>
</body>
```

Comment: yeah that's working, but i want to import elements offline. please help

Comment: @AnvarErkinov offline means?

Comment: i mean, import links without internet connection. the code you write needs internet connection, right?

Comment: @AnvarErkinov Have you tried this? https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/getting-the-code.html#installing-polymer